# Searching workaround for mysql limitation to reference top level query over 2 levels

Tags: mysql, join, reference, correlated-subquery

For the following intended mysql/mariadb query:

```
SELECT * FROM aktfv f
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM (
       SELECT * FROM labor1a WHERE pat_id = f.pat_id
 UNION SELECT * FROM labor2a WHERE pat_id = f.pat_id) i
) i ON i.pat_id = f.pat_id;
```

I get error 1054: Unknown column 'f.pat_id' in 'where clause',
apparently because of the limitation to refer to an outer table parameter only over 1 level.
I wanted to apply the 'where' clause because otherwise the 'union select' takes very very long.
Can anybody give me a hint for a workaround?

Comment: Your query has some large structural problems from what I can see.  You might want to add some sample data which explains what you are trying to do here.

Comment: labor1a and labor2a are similarly structured views on laboratory data from different sources in very different tables from different sources, belonging to patients who are listed in the view aktfv. I want to consider the laboratoy data from the different sources simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  f.* ,l.* FROM aktfv f join labor1a l on  l.pat_id = f.pat_id
 UNION 
SELECT  f.* ,l.* FROM aktfv f join labor2a l on l.pat_id = f.pat_id
```

Or am I missing something?